# Kotlin/Android selecting all elements in listView getchildat(i)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am currently making something on kotlin.

I was trying to make it so that when you click on individual items on the listView, it would become highlighted and "checked" as im using "CheckableLinearLayout" implementation.

However, unlike what I expected, this following code only selects the items currently within the view (~8, but there are 12 total).

Also, if I scroll up or down, the items that leave the window are automatically unselected... Thanks in advance.

```
    fun selectAll()
    {
        for (i in 0..rootView!!.list.childCount-1){
            var test = list.getChildAt(i) as CheckableLinearLayout
            test.setChecked(true)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set list items as selected after a scroll event by setting up an [OnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) in the listview. What do you mean by "the items currently within the view"?

Comment: "the items currently within the view", let me rephrase it. I meant the items(views) that are currently displayed on the screen. So if there are 10 items total on my adapter and the screen can only display 8 items, those 8 are the "the items currently within the view".